# Is my proof on the right track? (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

**The question:**

Suppose $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is an **orthonormal** set of (complex) $n\times1$ column vectors. Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\bullet v_i^\dagger=I_{n\times n}$$ where $\bullet$ represents matrix multiplication, $v_i^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of $v_i$ and $I_{n\times n}$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

**My attempt:**

Consider $$v_1^\dagger\bullet \left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\bullet v_i^\dagger\right) \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n \left(v_1^\dagger\bullet v_i\right)\bullet v_i^\dagger = (1)\bullet v_1^\dagger + \sum_{i=2}^n\left((0)\bullet v_i^\dagger\right) \equiv v_1^\dagger$$
Then $$v_1^\dagger\bullet \left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\bullet v_i^\dagger - I_{n\times n}\right) = \mathbf{0}_{1\times n}$$
Since $v_1^\dagger$ is not a zero vector, I am tempted to conclude that $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\bullet v_i^\dagger - I_{n\times n}$ is a zero matrix. Do I need, and how, to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\bullet v_i^\dagger - I_{n\times n}$ is not otherwise a matrix with linearly dependent columns? Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: The calculation is correct so far, but it is certainly possible for $v\bullet A$ to equal the zero vector without $A$ being the zero matrix (otherwise, the null space of a matrix would be an empty concept). That being said, your calculation for $v_1^\dagger$ should work for the other $v_i^\dagger$ as well; can you get some mileage out of that? (Alternatively, you can simply verify the desired equality entry by entry.)

Comment: What is the result of $$v_j^\dagger\bullet \left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\bullet v_i^\dagger\right)$$ for every $1 \leq j \leq n$?